# Prove $B^{-1}=I+B-B^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I've been trying to prove this for so many hours but nothing seems to work. Probably I am just missing something. Anyone has any idea about it?

The question is to prove: $B^{-1}=I+B-B^2$
Any suggestions are accepted!

I should mention that I have the values for $B$ and $B^{-1}$ but as it is asking for proof, I guess I am not allowed to use them.

Edit: as requested B is a 3x3 matrix and has an inverse ad det(B)!=0

B= \begin{bmatrix}1&3&2\\0&-1&4\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

Comment: This requires more context. What kind of matrix is B?

Comment: This is not true for a general matrix, only true when $B$ satisfies $B + B^2 - B^3 - I = 0$

Comment: Just added the information missing, thank you for your help :)

Comment: When you want to prove something, you use all the assumptions that you have. In this question, as you're given the value of $B$, you can use it. In fact, this is not true for all matrices. For example, take $B=2I$. Then $B^{-1}=1/2I$ but $I+B-B^2=-I$.

Comment: After editing, still not enough. The matrix $B$ I gave above can be taken to be 3x3 and has nonzero det.

Comment: added the matrix (thought I should not post it as maybe it wasn't necessary.) If I  solve it knowing all values (as I do) it works, but I was asking, as it is asking for proof, whether it is the right way to go.

Comment: @butterflyflyaway The question asks you to prove this for the given $B$, not for any general matrix. You should easily see that it's not true for all matrices. So just **compute** $B, B^2, B^3$ and **verify** that $B + B^2 - B^3 = I$

Comment: @butterflyflyaway You don't use specific values if you want to prove a general statement that holds for all objects of a certain kind. For a specific object, using its specefic value is generally the easiest way, and many times the only way.

Answer (score 2):

The relation is satisfied iff $B^3-B^2-B+I=0$. In other words you are asking if $B$ satisfies a certain polynomial relation $P(B)=0$ for some polynomial $P(t) \in \mathbb{Z}[t]$ (in your case $P(t)=t^3-t^2-t+1$). This only happens if the minimal polynomial of $B$ divides $P(t)$. So, in general: every time you have this type of question you should compute the minimal polynomial $m_B(t)$ and test with the Euclidean division algorithm if $m_B(t)$ divides $P(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that the eigenvalues of $B$ are $1$, $1$ and $-1$. So the characteristic polynomial is
$$p(\lambda)=(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+1)=\lambda^3-\lambda^2-\lambda+1$$
And by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $p(B)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

In general $$(I+B-B^2)(B) = B+B^2-B^3$$ and there is no reason to believe that it is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

$B = $\begin{bmatrix}1&3&2\\0&-1&4\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

$B^2 = $ \begin{bmatrix}1&0&16\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

$B^3 = $ \begin{bmatrix}1&3&18\\0&-1&4\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

Now it's easy to verify that $B + B^2 - B^3 = I$